# How to read and write on private fields in java

Tags: java, variables, static

i want write/read a private variable ...
please look at to my code :

```
 public class Date {
 Date time = new Date();
 private int year,month,day ;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("My text :");
       Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       int year,month,day ;
       String error = "My text " ;
       String monthName = null ;
       System.out.println("Year :") ;
       year = myScanner.nextInt();
       setYear(year) ;
       System.out.println("Month :") ;
       month = myScanner.nextInt();
       setMonth(month) ;
       System.out.println("Day :") ;
       day = myScanner.nextInt();
       setDay(day) ;
       switch(month) {
       case 1 :
           monthName = "Name of this month in my language" ;
           break ;
       case 2 :
           monthName = "Name of this month in my language" ;
           break ;
       case 3 :
           monthName = "Name of this month in my language" ;
           break ;
       case 4 :
           monthName = "Name of this month in my language" ;
           break ;
       case 5 :
           monthName = "Name of this month in my language" ;
           break ;
       case 6 :
           monthName = "Name of this month in my language" ;
           break ;
       case 7 :
           monthName = "Name of this month in my language" ;
           break ;
       case 8 :
           monthName = "Name of this month in my language" ;
           break ;
       case 9 :
           monthName = "Name of this month in my language" ;
           break ;
       case 10 :
           monthName = "Name of this month in my language" ;
           break ;
       case 11 :
           monthName = "Name of this month in my language" ;
           break ;
       case 12 :
           monthName = "Name of this month in my language" ;
           break ;
           default : System.out.println("Error !") ;
       }
       if(day >= 1 && day <=31){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null ,getYear() + " " + monthName + " " + getDay()) ;
       }
       else {
           System.out.println(error);
       }
    }
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }
    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }
    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }
    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

}
```

i want read/write private year/month/day ...
 just private ...
i have create their accessible function but i receive an error about ("Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setYear(int) from the type Date" and i can't fix it .. 
can you help me ?

Comment: Whenever you get the error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static blah", it means you need to make an instance of the class and use the instance to access blah.

Comment: `class Date { Date time = new Date(); ...}` no, No, NO. Two major errors. (1) don't ever use for name of your class name used by JVM, (2) this small fragment is best recipe for StackOverflow error, since each of your `Date` instance will want to create its own `Date` instance, which will also want its own `Date` instance, ...

Comment: Yes, what Pshemo said, if you really want to have an instance of class instead that very class, make it static like `static ClassName instanceName = new ClassName();`. `static` keyword makes sure that there is always *one* existence, never more or less.

Comment: Your problem isn't connected with access modifiers like `private`. Your  `main()` method belongs to the whole class and can't get access to non-static fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should try to refrain from mixing your main method within your `Date` class. You can create another class with the `main` which looks like this (to test run your codes):

```
class DateRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Date d = new Date();
        System.out.println(d.getDay()); //getting variables from Date object.
    }
}

class Date{
    //Your usual implementation (members and constructor)
}
```

Once you do that, it will be easy for you to work with the variables in the class.

---

I am not sure whether your school wants you to name your class as Date. If I were you I will try to name it as something different like `MyDate` instead of `Date` as there is already a Date class in Java.

> i receive an error about ("Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setYear(int) from the type Date" and i can't fix it .. can you help me ?

You need to understand what are `static` members. It is giving you error because you are trying to access non-static members from your `main` which is a static method.

**2 ways to stop the errors:**

1. Make your variables in the class as static (**Strongly discourage** you from doing this though)
2. Create an instance of Date and access the instance variables from the Date Object.(This is what you should be doing)

**Example:**

```
Date d = new Date();  //Create an object of Date
```

Now you can easily access all the Date's memebers via it's instance.

**Example:**

```
d.getDay();
d.setDay(5);
d.getMonth();
d.setMonth(7);
d.getYear();
d.setYear(2015);
```

You can now write these within the main method.

> How to read and write on private fields in java

By creating an object and use the getters and setters like above.